# Insert word between each matching line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am wondering how I can check the end of the file in while loop.
What I am doing here is if there is some word, such as, "pineapple", "apple", "onion", "orange", or etc, I want to find lines including specific words by using grep command and make some comment "window". For example, if I use `grep 'a' 'file'`, then it will find "pineapple", "apple", and "orange". Then, finally I want to make it printed like "pineapple, window, apple, window, orange, window", something like this. So, I would like to make some condition in while or for loop. Any helps will be really appreciated.

edit:
Sample inputs

```
apple
banana
pineapple
orange
mandu
ricecake
meat
juice
milk
onion
green onion
```

Expected outputs when using grep command --> `grep 'a' 'file name'`

```
apple
window
banana
window
pineapple
window
orange
window
mandu
window
ricecake
window
meat
window
```

Comment: Can you show some sample input and expected output?  I'm not sure how the "end of file" and your "window" correlate.

Comment: apple
banana
pineapple
orange
mandu
ricecake
meat
juice
milk
onion
green onion -- > above words are words in input file, and then whenever I use grep command, then if it is matched it will print "window" with the word matched, such as apple, window, pineapple, window .. something like this as I explained above.

Comment: Sorry for making you guys confused, I edited, hopefully you guys could understand what I am trying to do

Comment: So you just want to put `window` between each match?  What does the end of the file have to do with this?

Comment: Yea, cause I wanted to make some condition to use for or while loop.

Comment: The title says "between", but your question actually seems to be "after". In your example, you have `window` as the last line of the result, so it's not between anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Using awk

To print `window` after every line that matches `a`:

```
$ awk '/a/{print; print "window"}' filename
apple
window
banana
window
pineapple
window
orange
window
mandu
window
ricecake
window
meat
window
```

**How it works**

`/a/{...}` selects lines that match the regex `a`.  For each such line, the commands in curly braces are executed.

`print` prints the line containing the match

`print "window"` prints `window`.

## Using sed

```
$ sed -n '/a/{s/$/\nwindow/; p}' filename
apple
window
banana
window
pineapple
window
orange
window
mandu
window
ricecake
window
meat
window
```

**How it works**

`-n` tells sed not to print unless we explicitly as it to.

`/a/{...}` selects lines that match the regex `a`.  For those lines, the commands in curly braces are executed.

`s/$/\nwindow/` adds a newline and `window` after the end of the current line.

`p` prints.

Comment: sed also allows p as a flag on s command: `sed -n '/a/s/$/\nwindow/p'`

Answer (score 3):

```
$ grep 'a' file | sed 'a\window'
apple
window
banana
window
pineapple
window
orange
window
mandu
window
ricecake
window
meat
window
```

This uses your original `grep` command and then appends the word `window` after each resulting line using the `a` ("append") command in GNU `sed` (standard `sed` requires a newline after the `\` and at the end of the inserted text, but GNU `sed` is a bit more forgiving).

Alternatively, using only GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -n -e '/a/{p;a\window' -e '}' file
apple
window
banana
window
pineapple
window
orange
window
mandu
window
ricecake
window
meat
window
```

The `sed` expression prints every line containing the letter `a` and then appends the string `window`.

Answer (score 2):

The shell way can be used as so:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    case "$line" in
        *a*) printf "%s\nwindow\n" "$line"
    esac
done < input.txt
```

This combines the typical `while IFS= read -r line; do...done < file.txt` loop for reading files, `case` statement to match lines that contain particular character, and `printf` for printing that extra `window` line.